# Replacing newline escape '\n' with an escaped newline escape '\\n' using sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am trying to replace the literal term `\n` (not a newline, the literal) by the literal `\\n` using `sed`. I've tried this:

```
echo '"Refreshing \n\n\n state prior"' | sed 's/\\n/\\\n/g'
```

This "works" but I need it to output the literal characters `\\n`.  Right now I end up with something like this:

```
"Refreshing \
\
\
 state prior"
```

Is there a way for me to maintain the `\\n` in `sed` output?

Comment: When I run this command my output is `"Refreshing \n\n\n state prior"`

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are trying to do here exactly. Does your input contain `\n` or does it contain actual newlines? What are you trying to have in your output? `\n`? `\\n`? `\n<newline>`?

Comment: I want to have `\\n`.  I should mention this is in bash on Ubuntu 14.04.  When I save the output to a variable and echo that variable, the `\n` is omitted and I'm left with just `\`.

Comment: btw `echo "Refreshing \n\n\n state prior"` will print `Refreshing \n\n\n state prior` which is the output you want

Comment: Just caught a typo in my question, I want the output to be `\\n`.  I said this in my comment but the question had `\n`.  Sorry about that.

Comment: I believe the confusion hek2mgl is having comes from the fact that `echo` is poorly specified as to its behavior with escapes in the arguments. Some (e.g. coreutils and the bash builtin) require `-e` to evaluate escapes. Others (and I believe possibly the spec) do not. This is why the general recommendation is to use `printf` which is *much* better specified and consistent.

Comment: Minus 1 because the question is super hard to get - and then you changed the problem after answers had been posted.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I'll keep that in mind when asking other questions.  However, someone did understand what I wanted and was able to provide an acceptable solution.

Comment: @tubaguy50035 Sounds good! Post edited, down-vote reverted.

Comment: @EtanReisner I admit that for a moment when answering I forgot about `-e` (while knowing about it). This happens sometimes to me when I read a question and believe what the OP writes. (I mean he wrote "I want to replace newlines") .. Conclusion: Never trust the OP! ;)

Comment: `awk '{gsub(/\\n/, "\\\\n"); print}'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get `\\n` add one more `\`to your sed:

```
echo "Refreshing \n\n\n state prior" | sed 's/\\n/\\\\n/g'
```

What you were trying to do with `\\\n` was to print `\` character and then add `\n` which caused a new line.

Comment: @tubaguy50035 I'm curious what is the problem with my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30785781/171318 . It looks much simpler, but probably I'm missing something?

Comment: @hek2mgl That's not the output I was looking for.  If I could just output the input, I wouldn't be here asking this question.  :)

Comment: @tubaguy50035 Please try `echo "hello\nworld"` how much lines does it output? Do you see that you *indeed* posted a non-sense problem?

Comment: I wanted one line of output, with the literal characters `\\n`.  This answer does that and has an explanation of what I was doing wrong.  Thanks for your positive feedback though.

Comment: Desn't work for me. Try `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g'`.

Answer (score 2):

Change `sed 's/\\n/\\\n/g'` to:

```
sed 's/\\n/\\\\n/g'
```

If you want to replace `\n` with `\\n`

Comment: Desn't work for me. Try `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g'`.

Comment: @EduardoLucio : What you are trying to do is something totally different. You are replacing newline with literal `\n`.