# Print new line as string literal in unix or shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

Hi I have a shell script that has

```
variable="apple banana monkey"
```

I want it to be

`apple\nbanana\nmonkey`

But when I try and execute

`echo $variable | tr ' ' '\n'`

It results to

```
apple
banana
monkey
```

I want to get the actual literal of new line and not the evaluated value.

I have tried echo -e or echo -n or even put numerous escapes \\ but to no avail.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing newline escape '\n' with an escaped newline escape '\\n' using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30785650/replacing-newline-escape-n-with-an-escaped-newline-escape-n-using-sed)

Comment: @MickaelB. We tried this already.

Answer (score 0):

`tr` command translates chars into chars by performing a 1 to 1 mapping. You are asking the tool to translate a space into two chars, which is something that cannot be done with `tr`.

If you accept a command switch, you can try with `sed`:

```
echo "$variable" | sed  's/ /\\n/g'
```

Comment: Thanks, this does not work in our environment. Still evaluates the new lines.

Comment: It doesn't work because it replace the space with a `\n`. You need one more backslash `'s/ /\\\n/g'` should work.